# How to properly position text and icon on a button with html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm using Font awesome for Facebook icon and an image for google.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

```css
    #Loginbuttons{
     justify-content: space-between;
     padding-top: 20%;
     text-align:center;
    }
    .Google{
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
     border-radius: 19px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 2vh;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     border-radius: 13px;
     width: 90%;
     height: 8vh;
     color: black;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left:2em;
    }
    .Facebook{
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
     border-radius: 19px;
     background-color: #3A559F;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 2vh;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     border-radius: 13px;
     width: 90%;
     height: 8vh;
     color: black;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left:2em;
    }
    .fa-facebook-square{
     color: white;
     font-size: 4vh;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
     <div id="imageDiv">
     <br>
     <img src="boxfarmingGreen2.png">
     </div>
     <div id="Loginbuttons">
     <button class="button Google">Sign in with Google &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="googleLogo.png" id="googleLogo"></button><br><br>
     <button class="button Facebook">Continue with Facebook &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

If someone can explain what am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: `display: flex; ` is a good start. Try wrapping the text inside the button in a `<span>` tag and see if it works. Flex needs children elements to work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the Facebook button using alignments with the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Hope this helps.

```css
#Loginbuttons {
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Google {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 19px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 8vh;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.Facebook {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 19px;
  background-color: #3A559F;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Added */
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 8vh;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.fa-facebook-square {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <div id="Loginbuttons">
    <button class="button Facebook">
      <span>Continue with Facebook</span>
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only have a problem that now the button is not in the center

Answer (score 0):

You should not add height to the button if you need to make it specific size you should use padding and also I add 2 subclasses for your icon and image tag. Good luck

```css
#Loginbuttons{
     justify-content: space-between;
     padding-top: 20%;
     text-align:center;
    }
    
    .Google{
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
     border-radius: 19px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 14px;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     border-radius: 13px;
     width: 90%;
     color: black;
     text-align: left;
     padding:1em;
      padding-left:2em;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .Google img{
      float:right !important;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .Facebook{
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
     border-radius: 19px;
     background-color: #3A559F;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 14px;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     border-radius: 13px;
     width: 90%;
     color: black;
     text-align: left;
     padding:1em;
      padding-left:2em;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .fa-facebook-square{
     color: white;
     font-size: 4vh;
    }
    
    .Facebook i{
      float:right !important;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
     <div id="imageDiv">
     <br>
     <img src="boxfarmingGreen2.png">
     </div>
     <div id="Loginbuttons">
     <button class="button Google">Sign in with Google <img src="googleLogo.png" id="googleLogo"></button><br><br>
     <button class="button Facebook">Continue with Facebook <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></button>
     </div>
    </div>
```